# Socialite: Login with Google Client error

Tags: laravel, laravel-socialite

I'm using stateless fromUserToken

and this is the error I'm getting:

```
"errors": {
        "error": "Client error: `GET https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo?prettyPrint=false` resulted in a `401 Unauthorized` response:\n{\n  \"error\": \"invalid_request\",\n  \"error_description\": \"Invalid Credentials\"\n}\n",
        "code": 401
    }
```

this is my endpoint that I use, it worked with all the sections I have in

```
public function authenticate (Request $request, $provider) {
        
        //Validate provider
        


        // Authenticate
        $userSocial  = null;
        try {
            if ($provider == 'twitter') {
                $userSocial = Socialite::driver('twitter')->userFromTokenAndSecret($request->token, $request->token_secret);
            } else {
                $accessToken = $request->token;
                $userSocial = Socialite::driver($provider)->stateless()->userFromToken($accessToken);
            }
        } catch (\Exception $e) {
            return $this->respondError('Login error',[
                'error' => $e->getMessage(),
                'code' => $e->getCode()
            ],401);
        }
        
        $user       =   User::where([
            'provider' => $provider,
            'provider_id' => $userSocial->id
        ])->first();

        if($user){
            $token = $user->createToken('api')->plainTextToken;
            return $this->respondWithToken($token, 'Logged in successfully', false);
        } else {
            $user = User::create([
                'name'          => $userSocial->getName() ?: 'Apple User',
                'email'         => $userSocial->getEmail(),
                'image'         => $userSocial->getAvatar(),
                'provider_id'   => $userSocial->getId(),
                'provider'      => $provider,
            ]);
            $token = $user->createToken('api');
            return $this->respondWithToken($token, 'Registered successfully', true);
        }
    }
```

Any Idea how to solve it?
and this is the code I used

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The token that I was getting was jwt token, not access token. so It had problems with decoding it with stateless socialite function.

Comment: How did you fix this issue?

Answer (score 2):

when requesting for authorization, you should set the `response_type` and `scope` url parameter like below:

```
scope = profile email
response_type = token
```